# How to not expose the data structure in an object while accepting a collection of items with named parameters?

Tags: kotlin, fluent-interface, named-parameters

Most of the time, we can replace a fluent interface with named parameters.

```
class Cart {
    fun withItems(vararg items: Item) = this
}

fun aCart(): Cart {
    TODO()
}

class Item

fun anItem(): Item {
    TODO()
}

fun main() {
    aCart().withItems(anItem(), anItem(), anItem())
}
```

The code snippet above can abstract away the data structure by leveraging `vararg` feature of the language.

I wondered if there was a way to achieve the same thing by dint of named parameters.

Can I come up with something that looks as follows?

```
class Cart(val withItems: Collection<Item>)

class Item

fun main() {
    Cart(
        withItems = { Item(), Item() }
    )
}
```

Comment: Not with the curly braces like that.  You can always write `withItems = listOf(Item(), Item())`

Comment: Dude, this was what I had emphasized in the question. I don't want to expose the data structure to store those elements. By doing this, you expose that you use a list data structure to store those items which leads to breaking the encapsulation.

Comment: That is the best you can do in Kotlin.  Sorry if you were hoping for another answer.